# How do I align my div on the y-axis, proper way? CSS/flex

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a login page, and have 3 SVG images, where as 2 on the top, one one bottom right. They are all positioned absolute, where the container is displayed relative.

Now I basically want a div that's on 30/40% of the top of the outer container. What would be the best approach to go over this?

1) Make a div that's a fixed height, but this is not responsive and I will work with media queries.

So it's about the blue container as displayed on the on the image, where as the red boxes do not have a height as they are abstract.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHaDY.png)
Any idea's?

This div should be on 30% on the top of the height.

What approach would be the best for this?

Comment: add your html and css that demostrate what you've done and your issue. a screenshot is useless without code. your codes can be anything , reread : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   ;) Welcome on SO

Comment: Kindly refer to this [ask]

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but using flexbox you would use sth like 
`justify-content:center` for your container.

Comment: For vertical alingment, you may consider using `flex-flow: column;` on the container, then setting `flex-basis` as a percentage on the flex-items. Thus you can control the relative height of the elements inside the container, if this was the question.

Comment: @terminus.technicus This was actually the question. Thankyou my man, you are a hero!

Comment: @BrandonSerge I'm glad I could help. I posted my solution as an answer. Please vote it up and accept it as answer, that will make my day, too. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For vertical alignment, you may use `flex-flow: column;` on the container. Then set `flex-basis` as a percentage on the flex-items. Thus you can control the relative height of the child elements inside the container.

See: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/86ohszba/1/)